# can someone help me with this malfunctioning align environment

Tags: errors, align

I have narrowed the source of the error down to the following bit of code:

```
\begin{align*}
$\swarrow \sum F_{x\textquoteright} = 0 &= -D+ (m g-\nabla \rho g) \sin{(\theta)}$ \\
$\nwarrow \sum F_{y\textquoteright} = 0 &= L- (m g-\nabla \rho g) \cos{(\theta)}$
\end{align*}
```

and this is the error I keep getting:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
           }
l.20
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the `\textquoteright ` suppose to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align` puts you in math mode, so you should not use `$`.

[image: equation]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\swarrow \sum F_{x\textquoteright} = 0 &= -D+ (m g-\nabla \rho g) \sin{(\theta)} \\
\nwarrow \sum F_{y\textquoteright} = 0 &= L- (m g-\nabla \rho g) \cos{(\theta)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Update:* You may want to turn your `\textquoteright` either into `\prime` or directly into `'`.

[image: update]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\swarrow \sum F_{x'} = 0 &= -D+ (m g-\nabla \rho g) \sin{(\theta)} \\
\nwarrow \sum F_{y'} = 0 &= L- (m g-\nabla \rho g) \cos{(\theta)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```